# What happens when sink transition is enabled

Tags: petri-nets

Well I guess it is only a matter of definition but I've failed to find certain answer to the following question:

In a Petri net if transition has k inputs and zero outputs what is considered to happen when transition fires? Do we have just k - 1 token left and then just transition is not enabled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Firing the transition just consumes one token from each of its input places.